# What causing session identifier not updated issue?

Tags: php, security, session

I just have encountered the threat during the web application security test. I have reviewed the code and unable to find out why this would be happening any recommendation to resolve it will be appriciated, is this related to redoing php code ?

Please help as soon as possible.

[UPDATED]

Change session identifier values after login

I am not able to resolve due to lack of understanding, do I have to change the session keys to different one after moving from one page to another page

It also suggest that "Verify that only session identifiers are tracked in the login Management"

Variant Reasoning
The test result seems to indicate a vulnerability because the session identifiers in the Original Request (on the left) and in the Response (on the right) are identical. They should have been updated in the response.

Comment: Not enough detailed to help you...

Comment: @justnajm Will You expand your Problem, can you show snippets??

Comment: I have updated the details, their is no source code error as security scan is not authrize to read code, it is just attempting fake login and going throug each page for vulnerability tests

Answer (score 0):

I did some debuging and encounter the session hijack problem in the code, same session id was used for different login attempts on same computer that was causing "session identifier not updated" security error because after you logout any one can use the session id to attempt login, therefore I used

```
session_regenerate_id (true)// it regenerate id and delete old id on machine
```